# Warning before saving form implement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, warnings

I am working on an app where Admin can publish a welcome message to the public page. I need to have a warning message before Publishing the message, basically, after they click ‘Publish to Public page’ show a warning which says “You are about to publish this content to the world, on your public status page. It will be visible to all internet users, not just your colleagues. Click ‘OK’ to publish or ‘Cancel’ to go back.

If they click ‘Cancel’ provide a warning like ‘Are you sure you want to Cancel? Click ‘OK’ to delete your Edits’

I have the first of the warning so far:

My form

```
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id ="edit-public-page-form" class="message-form" action="<%= public_page_path %>" method="post" data-image-path="<%= upload_image_noticeboards_path %>">
            <textarea class="noticeEditor" name="content" style="width: 100%; height:340px;">
              <%= @welcome_message %>
            </textarea>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :_method, "put" %>
            <br>
            <%= t('statusx.public_page_link')%>
            <%= link_to "https://demo.getvetter.com/public", target: :_blank %>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button
            id='saveButton'
            class="btn btn-primary tn-w-m"><%= t('statusx.save') %></button>
            <button id="cancel_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-w-m"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
          </form>
```

```
  $('#edit-public-page-form').submit(function(event) {
    return confirm('You are about to publish this content to the world, on your public status page. It will be visible to all internet users, not just your colleagues. Click \'OK\' to publish or \'Cancel\' to go back.');
  });
```

I just don't know how to implement the second part of the warning.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: It's a bit confusing to have a warning on a warning.  If they click cancel, I'd just leave them on the page, why delete their edits?

Comment: @max  This has now been sorted and both warnings are implemented

Comment: @dbugger I totally agree with you but this was client requirement :)
=>  After they click ‘Publish to Public page’ show a warning which says “You are about to publish this content to the world, on your public status page. It will be visible to all internet users, not just your colleagues. Click ‘OK’ to publish or ‘Cancel’ to go back. 

If they click ‘Cancel’ provide a warning ‘Are you sure you want to Cancel? Click ‘OK’ to delete your Edits’

Comment: Talk them out of it -- this is not by any means wise or user friendly.

Comment: @dbugger PM is on it. Let's see what the outcome